# Checking, if string is in list in python doesn't work

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm making a python program in tkinter and i have a problem. I want to run a program, but i need to check if program's name is in a file. I'm using this code:

```
def run_module(module_name):
    file_py = open("modules_py.txt")
    temp_py = file_py.read().splitlines()
    print(module_name)
    print(type(module_name))
    print(temp_py)
    if module_name in temp_py:
        file_exist = os.path.exists(module_name + '.py')
        if file_exist == True:
            os.system("start " + module_name + ".py")
        else:
            print("File doesn't exist")
    else:
        print("???")
```

Everything looks nice to me, but i have a result that is diffrent from my expectation. Here it is:

```
test
<class 'str'>
['test', 'test2']
???
```

I thought, that "test.py" will start, but it didn't start.

Do you know why do i have that result? Why "test.py" doesn't start? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add `print(repr(module_name))`. This will show whitespace and control characters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please check if your variable `module_name` has any extra space in it
because a string must match to satisfy this condition

```
if module_name in temp_py:
```

because according to your output it says your string does not exists

Comment: Thank you! Variable 'module_name' was read from file too, but it was read with extra space. I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looping trough your array (temp_py) and remove any kind of whitespace, newline or invisible character with strip().

If that solve the issue, you might want to clean your "modules_py.txt